# How to kill a pro with Protection 4 diamond set before he eats his enchanted golden apple?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Once they eat an **enchanted** golden apple. They become very hard to kill, they have like **1 stack** of them. They also have good swords (Sharp V, Fire aspect II, Unbreaking III). I can brew and use potions but even **strength II** and **Speed II** together, don't seem that effective.

> **My server uses 1.8 battle mechanics**

Comment: If they're expecting a fight, the only way you can really beat them is by having similar power levels or equipment. If you start shooting them from far away, they will probably still be able to eat an apple, but at least you'll have some time to get away if they commence chasing. Alternatively, set a trap for them to walk into that will kill them instantly - a pit trap that drops an anvil on their heads, for example.

Comment: I play survival and the only place you can pvp is the pvparena you can't break blocks and place them there

Comment: Hi User!  I  honestly don't believe we can really give a proper answer to this since it's very subjective. :( The only way to win is to out-DPS your opponent, but the limitations to that truth is really dependant on many factors. (Like, can you just dump lava on them? trap them? have them run into an enderman? Is it a set area or open map? Can you spleef them out of the world? ect..)

Answer (score 1):

Too bad there is no splash milk to purge the opponents.
Anyway, it's pretty simple in words, but hard to do in the arena.

First you need to understand what the apple actually does in order to counter it.

```
Absorption IV (2:00)   - 2 Hearts * Level as absorb shield = 8 extra Hearts to kill off (cannot be restored)
Regeneration II (0:20) - 0.4 Hearts / s restored * 20s = 8 Hearts
Fire Resistance (5:00) - immune to fire
Resistance (5:00)      - 20% less damage taken per level
```

So if someone uses the apple at full health the regeneration goes into the void. You have to kill off the absorb shield anyway, which can only be restored by a new absorb effect. They just have 8 Hearts more than you and take 20% less damage, which is doable.

So you have a few options:

- Survive. Don't go for the direct kill. You have less life (or no absorb) and direct combat gets you killed. Use the arena, look for obstacles, dance with them.
- Get an enchanted apple yourself to make it even or at least dance to buy some time to let some buffs fall off.
- Outgear them (equal gear is pretty much required, better gear helps more)
- use Splash potions for some nice debuffs or direct damage (Poison, Weakness, etc.)
- learn to move (anticipate their moves and dodge/counter them, etc.)

The more points you meet the easier it gets.
You still need to always keep them busy. PvP is like [Hannibal Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_%22Hannibal%22_Smith) said in the A-Team movie:

> Time. Give me a minute, I'm good. If I've got an hour, I'm great. You give
>   me six months, I'm unbeatable.

Comment: 1st and 2nd option is not effective because once their enchanted gapple buffs fall off they just re-eat another one. You can't run away forever because :1 the arena is a medium sized one, 2 they use speed potion to outrun you, 3 when you are trying to escape, other players will think that you have few hearts and so they will also try to kill you, 4 they will try to use their bows. Outgearing them is hard due to the fact that they already have maxed out gear and thorns is a rare enchantment. splash potions would work if they stopped moving. 5th option dodging is hard as they use speed potion.

Comment: There is no other way really. If you can't hit them with a debuff and you have worse gear you're pretty much doomed. They'll do too much damage in direct combat, if you don't dodge.

Answer (score 1):

1.8 combat? Auto clicker with really good armor/sword. This is pretty cheaty though. 1.8- combat was made in a way that you can be able to do this though.

Yes, I know this question is 3 years old.